# Store files in web server memory- python CGI

Tags: python, cgi, web, file-handling

I have to read large files every time i run cgi application on a web server....is there a way i can read files into memory at once when web server(Apache) is started and keep in memory?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, simple because CGI programs aren't kept in memory, ever. You may consider a different architecture, like [WSGI](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/).